# ASP.NET Core 6 / Entity Framework Core: relationships don't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-6.0

I can't deal with this problem and I hope you can help me.

I have two models `User` and `Friendship`. In `Friendship` if I relate to `RequestUser` or `ReceiveUser`, I get the correct data.

But `RequestedFriendships` and `ReceivedFriendships` in `User` is always null (there are rows in the database that should correlate with these lists). Is it possible at all to achieve that?

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public string? Password { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Friendship> RequestedFriendships { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Friendship> ReceivedFriendships { get; set; }
}

public class Friendship
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? RequestUserId { get; set; }
    public int? ReceiveUserId { get; set; }

    public FriendshipStatus Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual User RequestUser { get; set; }
    public virtual User ReceiveUser { get; set; }
}
```

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Friendship>()
            .HasOne(f => f.RequestUser)
            .WithMany(u => u.RequestedFriendships)
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.RequestUserId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);

modelBuilder.Entity<Friendship>()
            .HasOne(f => f.ReceiveUser)
            .WithMany(u => u.ReceivedFriendships)
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.ReceiveUserId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
```

This is my code for now.

Comment: It would be better if you could share the code you are using to retrieve the user object to make more accurate diagnosis.

Comment: Missing `Include`? Side note: the foreign keys should be `int` not `in?`.

Comment: @GertArnold Yes missing include was the problem. Problem solved.